# p:commandButton in p:treeTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Does somebody exist who has achieved using `p:commandButton` or `p:commandLink` or `h:commandButton` or `h:commandLink` in a p:treeTable successfully in 3.0?

I tried but only the commandLink/Button of root element of treeTable works as i expected.

If it is not possible can you advise some other treeTable in some other component library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try openfaces (http://openfaces.org/)
they have TreeTable and many other great components
http://openfaces.org/demo/treetable/TreeTable_basicFeatures.jsf

Answer (score 1):

Its a Primefaces bug...    [Commands (button and link) inside Tree Nodes do not work](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3230)

You need to get 3.0.1 or 3.1 (snapshots)

here's the links

[3.1-SNAPSHOT](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.1-SNAPSHOT/)

[3.0.1-SNAPSHOT](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/)

Here some more info about the issue discussed...[CommandButton/Link inside p:tree doesnt work?](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17244)

Answer (score 0):

Put your command code in a column.

```
    <p:treeTable
        var="tnode"
        value="#{myBean.dataModel}">
        <p:column >
        commandLink code
        </p:column>

   </p:treeTable
```